# Help in a proof of a result in Hungerford's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

I need help to proof the last part of this corollary:

[image]

I didn't understand the part (IV) because the author proves just the canonical projection case and the statement says "*every* nonzero homomorphism of rings $R\to S$ is a monomorphism".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every non-zero homomorphism of rings $R\to S$ is a monomorphism, then certainly the canonical projections are. On the other hand, if $h:R\to S$ is a surjective homomorphism, then $S\cong R/\ker h$, and you’re essentially looking at the canonical projection $\pi:R\to R/\ker h$ anyway.

Comment: I don't type as quickly as I should. Your answer posted while I was pecking away (and messing up).

Comment: Thank you Brian, as always when I have a question, you get directly into the core of my doubt.

Comment: @user42912: You're welcome; glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the fact that the kernel of the homomorphism is an ideal of $R$. If $R$ has no proper ideals, what are the choices for the kernel? What do these choices say about the homomorphism? Conversely, when would the projection $R \rightarrow R/I$ be a monomorphism, $I$ an ideal of $R$?